# MURA CMS url's redirection

Tags: url, redirect, content-management-system, mura

I'm currently using MURA software. How could I manage my URL redirection not just inside the domain, but outside too. Because now when I get into settings and trying to switch redirect from one page to another  I get just static displaying site.com and dynamically switched url where it is redirected with switcher of type of redirection. Also I need from www to non www redirection. Could please anyone help?

I'm watching through {context}/config/settings.ini.cfm  but I can't understand where is the spot. Maybe it is not there.

[Image of Interface for redirecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykBJz.png)